# how to match query string and clean url in htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Here is my dynamics url i dont't know how to write RewriteCond to capture and match query strings and clean my dynamics urls
.
here is my dynamic url

http://www.125books.com/search-bk?s=5&kw=thermo&ser=y

i want to change it to

http://www.125books.com/search-bk/5/thermo/y

kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+search-bk\?s=([0-9]+)&kw=([^&]+)&ser=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search-bk/%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^search-bk/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /search-bk?s=$1&kw=$2&ser=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sir not working here is my htaccess file                      Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]